Writing this switch function (typescript) from Prisma-speak to Drizzle-speak
I'm following the "Add Clerk Authentication & Stripe Payments to your NextJS tRPC Application"  tutorial which uses T3 app + Prisma + Clerk.
I've started my T3 app with Drizzle ORM.
I need help converting this specific switch function written in Prisma-speak to Drizzle-speak please!
const { id } = evt.data;
  const eventType = evt.type;

  switch (eventType) {
    case "user.created": {
      const count = await db.account.count({
        where: {
          userId: id!,
        },
      });

      if (!count) {
        await db.account.create({
          data: {
            userId: id!,
          },
        });
      }
    }

    default: {
      console.error(`The event type: ${eventType} is not configured`);
    }
  }

I've tried this but get errors:
//Check to see if userID already exists
    case "user.created": {
      // https://orm.drizzle.team/learn/guides/count-rows
      const [{count = 0}] = await db.select({value: count(users.id)}).from(users).where(eq(users.id, id))

//if count is zero then create account by just passing userID
      if(!count){
        // https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/insert
        await db.insert(users).values({name: id})
      }
    }

    default: {
      console.error(`The event type: ${eventType} is not configured`);
    }
  }


Using Drizzle ORM
import { db } from './your-drizzle-setup'; // Import Drizzle DB instance

const { id } = evt.data;
const eventType = evt.type;

switch (eventType) {
  case "user.created": {
    const count = await db.account
      .where({ userId: id! })
      .count(); // Drizzle syntax for counting rows

    if (count === 0) {
      await db.account.create({
        data: {
          userId: id!,
        },
      });
    }
    break; // Ensure you break out of the case

  }

  default: {
    console.error(`The event type: ${eventType} is not configured`);
    break; // Ensure you break out of the default case
  }
}

